# facebook comments moderation

Tags: facebook, comments

I integrated multiple comment boxes to my site.

I have setup:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxx"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxx"/>
```

and:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxx";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

comment box:

```
<fb:comments href="http://www.someulr.com" num_posts="2" width="660"></fb:comments>
```

I also have an App with an AppID.

my second moderator can see all the comments in the comment moderation tool, but he can't delete them? Why that is not possible?

there is a second tab on the moderation tool, Moderateview, this is empty, also with my account.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can delete the comments totally. You can only remove them from your site. Moderate --> Hide post